# Spring Framework: Inserting another JSP file with a JSP file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, view, partial

So I have my Request Path set as mywebsite.com/project/id/12378912?section=data, which maps to a corresponding Controller/Action and returns "project/index.jsp".

Inside index.jsp, I want to check what section-parameter it is and insert the correct PartialView section (but... I want to go to the Controller/Action to process some logic). Is this possible?

I know I can do something like using (jsp:include) and insert another .jsp page, but I want to go to the Controller/Action (of that .jsp page) to run some logic to dynamically generate that .jsp page.

In ASP MVC, we had something similar...

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_" + (string)ViewData["projectSection"], "Project", new { id = Model.Id }); }
```

which was embedded into the master/bigger view container.

Comment: Depending on how you've set up your controllers, you could inject controller B into controller A as a dependency, call B's method to add its information to the model, and then use `jsp:include`.

Comment: Are there any examples/documentations of said technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<jsp:include page="${request.contextPath}/mvc/project/id/${ project.id }/_data"></jsp:include>
```

into the correct location on the web page is what I was looking for. This code snippet actually goes to the Controller, processes any logic, and then generates the view --> outputting onto the main/parent page.

Answer (score 0):

The request just returns the html generate by jsp, so you get the html result and then do what you want.